# Browser removes nested body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some basic pre-made html temapltes, some text elements within these templates are `editable`. The template is dynamically loaded into a wrapper div, edited and then saved. This works perfectly.

Basic example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="html-wrapper"></div>
```

**Json response and load template into** `#html-wrapper`

```
$('#html-wrapper').html(data.htmlTemplate);
```

**Save via ajax after editing**

```
data = {};
data.html = $('#html-wrapper').html();
// send via ajax
```

---

The above code saves everything fine. The only problem is - the templates `html` and `body` tags are stripped out by the browser. I assume the browser is trying to be clever by sripping out nested `html` and `body` tags. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Your question is not much clear

Comment: can you explain the question clear? or create a fiddle

Comment: You can render template in <iframe> tag.

Comment: If you are content editing, then you should not include the head and body tags anyway - if you need to allow editing of head content, then have a separate textarea to edit that bit (and a separate field in the db).  There is no way to get round what you are doing as you are creating invalid html and I think jQuery is smart enough to realise

Comment: It is being clever because more than one html/body tag is not permitted.